# Expontentiation is not working as I expect

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran. I am trying to compute a simple function, but I'm having trouble with the exponent. If I run the following:

```
module procedures

    contains

        double precision function f(x)
             f = x**sigma - alpha*x**sigma + 5
             return
        end function f   

end module procedures

program main
    use procedures

    parameter (alpha = 5.0, sigma = 2)
    write(6,"('f(3) = ',1f15.8)") f(3.0)

end program main
```

I get f(3) = 6, even though the answer should be -31. I feel like I'm missing something extremely basic about exponentiation.

Comment: Can you show your working to how you get to -31? And use `implicit none` in the module and try again.  I imagine you'll be a lot less surprised with this important part.

Comment: Thank you. Adding `implicit none` didn't help but I was able to resolve the problem by defining my parameters properly in another module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful with your modules. You defined alpha and sigma in the main program but not in the module therefore, alpha and sigma are equal to zero in the module, then: x** 0 - 0*x** 0 + 5 = 6 for any value of x.

You do not need another module for this. Define the parameters inside the module above. Since the main program uses this module, the values are valid in the module, in the main program, and any other program segment that has 'use procedures' in it.

Comment: `alpha` and `sigma` in the subroutine aren't equal to zero.  They are undefined.

Comment: i think we can say they are *evidently* zero..  I hardly think that fine point deserves a downvote!

Comment: Technically, they are undefined. I believe different compilers behave differently. gfortran sets static variables to zero but I believe iFort does not and they will have random values.

Comment: @agentp, I didn't downvote (there are good points in the answer) but I understand why someone would.  The "therefore" is too strong and implies that this is the correct behaviour.  While one may say "clearly the are zero otherwise the answer wouldn't be 6", this isn't helpful.  The user may well be using `francescalusfort` which, when given something other than Fortran code to compile produces a program which prints the current value of 6.  Answers should try not to normalize undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suppose that remark about default initialization in gfortran and ifort depends on using the different default values for optimization setting. Do  you normally run ifort -fp-model strict -O0 -zero-initialized-in-bss ?